# computing percentiles in a nested list and output in a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a nested list of participant ids and their visits. For each participant at each visit 2 variables are measured 10 times and the data structure is similar to the simulated data given by the R code. For participant [[1]] we have 3 visits corresponding to [[1]][[1]], [[1]][[2]] and [[1]][[3]]. Similarly for participant 2. I want to compute 25th and 75th quantiles for each patient at each visit and store it in a long dataframe as follows. Any help is appreciated.

```
set.seed(23)
ll <- lapply(1:2, FUN=function(i) replicate(3, matrix(rnorm(20), ncol=2), simplify=FALSE))


df<-data.frame(id=numeric(0),visit=numeric(0),col1.lower.ptile=numeric(0),col1.upper.ptile=numeric(0),col2.lower.ptile=numeric(0),col2.upper.ptile=numeric(0))
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Infact I have about 200 observations per participant per visit. Wanted to create a simple example. Let me update my code.

Comment: My code and question is updated.

Comment: If you are interested, here is a nice simplification that doesn't create a bunch of external objects: `ll <- lapply(1:2, FUN=function(i) replicate(3, matrix(rnorm(20), ncol=2), simplify=FALSE))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R approach using a boat-load of `*apply` functions.

```
# use R rapply to get in the nested list and apply pull out the quantiles from  the columns
myRList <- rapply(ll, function(x) apply(x, 2, quantile, probs=c(.25, .75)), how="list")
```

`rapply` goes into the nested structure, and `apply` pulls out the quantiles for each matrix by column. For the first patient, for example, this returns

```
myRList[1]
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
          [,1]       [,2]
25% 0.08238097 -0.5795292
75% 1.08541924  0.2856748

[[1]][[2]]
          [,1]       [,2]
25% -0.5572163 -0.9983007
75%  0.6329706  0.2190313

[[1]][[3]]
          [,1]       [,2]
25% -0.7966075 -0.4823147
75%  0.8378379  0.9661969
```

Note that each measurement is in a column, which is how R stores data in a matrix. Thus, we can pull out the data into the desired format using `c` to strip out the matrix class. To put this into a data.frame, use `vapply` and `c` to return a vector from each matrix, use `lapply` to run over each patient and return a list of vectors. Then use do.call with `rbind.data.frame` to return the desired data.frame.

```
dat <- cbind(id=rep(seq_along(ll), lengths(ll)),
             do.call(rbind.data.frame,
                     lapply(myRList, function(x) t(vapply(x, c, FUN.VALUE=numeric(4))))))
```

This returns

```
dat
  id          V1         V2         V3        V4
1  1  0.08238097 1.08541924 -0.5795292 0.2856748
2  1 -0.55721633 0.63297057 -0.9983007 0.2190313
3  1 -0.79660754 0.83783794 -0.4823147 0.9661969
4  2 -1.07159858 0.02937252 -0.4670312 0.6528579
5  2 -0.44806361 0.52761202  0.1081107 1.1419628
6  2 -0.72854367 0.55997887 -0.1397759 0.6157683
```

When you see that you can trust the results, we can simplify this to a single operation as follows.

```
dat <- cbind.data.frame(id=rep(seq_along(ll), lengths(ll)),
                        matrix(rapply(ll, function(x) apply(x, 2, quantile,
                                                            probs=c(.25, .75))), ncol=4))
```

Then set the variable names as desired.

Answer (score 1):

A similar solution with somewhat simpler syntax:

```
with(new.env(), {

    # compute quantiles
    q <- lapply(ll, lapply, apply, 2, quantile, prob = c(0.25, 0.75))

    # simplify to array
    a <- simplify2array(unlist(q, recursive = FALSE))

    # return dataframe
    data.frame(id = rep(seq_along(ll), lengths(ll)),
               visit = unlist(lapply(lengths(ll), seq)),
               col1.lower.ptile = a[1, 1, ],
               col1.upper.ptile = a[2, 1, ],
               col2.lower.ptile = a[1, 2, ],
               col2.upper.ptile = a[2, 2, ])
}) -> df

df
#  id visit col1.lower.ptile col1.upper.ptile col2.lower.ptile col2.upper.ptile
#1  1     1      -0.18320744       0.42239195       -0.1075228       0.82134959
#2  1     2      -0.30466626       0.72310699       -1.1047154      -0.05519628
#3  1     3      -0.69026613       0.08553756       -0.4338562       0.34916939
#4  2     1       0.08335451       0.59375988       -1.1392453       0.45905958
#5  2     2      -0.81078650       0.23024319       -0.8819546       0.33385295
#6  2     3      -1.15689954       0.82117652       -0.2739212       0.61445726
```

Notice that I put the whole thing inside a `with` so that the intermediate results `q` and `a` are automatically destroyed at the end, but this is not strictly necessary.